# How to work with Swing timer

Tags: java, swing, timer, jbutton

I'm trying to stop the program for a second using Swing Timer.

```
Timer timer = new Timer(10000,
   new ActionListener(public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}));
```

didn't work

```
public class Card extends JButton implements ActionListener {

    int numberClick = 0;

    public card() {
        addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        numberClick++;

        if(numberClick == 2) {
            Timer timer = new Timer(10000, );
            timer.start();
            numberClick = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to lack basic understanding of how the Timer works. Please read [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). The concept is fairly simple.

The first argument in the `Timer` constructor is the `delay`. Seems you have that part down. The second argument is the `ActionListener` that listens for the *"Timer Events"* (actually ActionEvents). An event is fired each delayed time. The callback (`actionPerformed`) contains what should be performed after that delay (tick). So whatever you want to happen after that second, put it in the `actionPerformed` of the timer's `ActionListener`.

Also if you only want it t occur once, you should call `timer.setRepeats(false);`. Also note, you are using `10000`, which is in milliseconds, so it's 10 seconds, not 1. You should change it to `1000`

Example Flow

```
JButton button = new JButton("Press Me");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Print after one second");
            }
        });
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
    }
});
```

> **Press Button → Wait One Second → Print Statement**